# Como fazer uma linha horizontal responsiva?

Tags: html, layout-responsivo

Não posso fazer simplesmente uma linha, porque, dependendo da página, ao invés de uma linha, gera continuação em outra linha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não seria melhor utilizar o `HR` para fazer isso?

```css
hr{
  border-color:#aaa;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  width:100%;  
}
```

```html
<hr/>
```

Se for necessário, basta formatar da maneira desejada, para que fique selhante ao `underline`. Você também pode usar Width:100% para garantir que seja responsivo.

Comment: Obrigado resolveu o que eu precisava.

Comment: Me ajudou muito também, Obrigada!

Answer (score 3):

Você poderia usar a tag `<hr />` ou o `border-bottom` em uma `div`

```css
#linha {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<div id="linha">
  conteudo da div
</div>

<div>
  conteudo da div
</div>

<hr />

<div>
  conteudo da div
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.